# How to connect to internet using Android Emulator telnet

Tags: android, android-emulator, telnet

How to connect to internet using Android Emulator. I tried using telnet localhost 5554 command but the following error comes:
Web page not available.

I am not using any proxy. I am using a USB modem device to connect to the internet.
Please help quickly!

Answer (score 0):

Whether you add internet permission in Manifest file?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: I cant connect to the internet using the browser itself. Isn't this for applications?